# C#: Null exception on assignment operator using two-dimensional arrays in WPF

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf, exception, null

I am trying to fill a two-dimensional array with objects of my class but the debugger marks it as if it had a null value in the assignment operator line and in the line after. I've created a default constructor to prevent that from being the problem. I need it to take the value of

```
   matrixOfButtons[i, n] = new SpecialButton(i, n);
```

But it won't, it will stay as null. Why is that if I am already assigning the value with another constructor in the line above?

```
   protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
    int NumberOfRows = 15;
    int NumberOfColumns = 6;
    // Create array with default constructor
    SpecialButton[,] matrixOfButtons = new SpecialButton[NumberOfRows, NumberOfColumns];
        for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfRows; i++)
        {
            for(int n = 0; n < NumberOfColumns; n++)
            {
                matrixOfButtons[i, n] = new SpecialButton(i, n);
                // THE PREVIOUS LINE AND THE ONES THAT FOLLOW DISPLAY 
                //A NULL VALUE FOR matrixOfButtons[i,n] IN THE DEBUGGER.
            }
        }
      }
```

Constructors for SpecialButton object

```
public SpecialButton()
        {
        }
public SpecialButton(int row, int column)
        {
            button = new ToggleButton();
            row += 1;
            column += 1;
            Grid.SetRow(button, row);
            Grid.SetColumn(button, column);
        }
```

Comment: If i replace your Special button with string, code compiles and runs wihtout errors so I would have to guess the issue is in the constructor for SpecialButton

Comment: [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31056492/edit) your question to include code that exhibits the problem.

Comment: @KnightFox: You are right, it does look like that is the problem, but I can't quite fix it. I've added the code for both the default constructor and the one with two parameters. Is there anything you can picture that might be causing the problem?

Comment: @DourHighArch: The code that exhibits the problem is the one I already added. However, I also added the constructors I implemented, as somebody suggested the problem might be in the constructors. Since this is my first attempt at C#/XAML/wpf I can't quite put my finger on it.

Comment: @KatieArriagaM, you could try putting a breakpoint and zeroing in on the line in the constructor where it fails.